# Paypal Button Multiple prices

Tags: button, paypal

I actually have this calculator http://tiergamerelo.net/2014/calc/

If you select a league and a division it will generate a diffent prices.

I need to know how exactly i can pass the price to the button.

An example http://boostbros.com/buy-boosting/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't see the problem here. If you put all inputs, with proper name attributes, this should be passed directly to your sever when clicking on the button.

However I can see a glitch, when I selected another product, the price disappeared, but that's JS related tho, which is out of scope in this thread.

Comment: I dont know how to pass a custom price to paypal. What attribute it uses to get the exactly price?

Comment: Ahh I see, Assuming that you are using the Common Payment Objects (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#common-payments-objects), you just need to add the Amount object into your request (on server side of course) with the price you got from the form.